# python save dictionary values to database

Tags: python, sql, database, dictionary

I have a Python dictionary like the below with a dictionary of books

```
[{'title': 'Game of Thrones', 'summary': 'summary detail', 'number': 4},
{'title': 'James and the Giant Peach', 'summary': 'summary detail', 'number': 1}]
```

I want to loop over the dictionary and save the values to a mysql DB, what would the best way to go about this? Any suggestions please

```
books.items() //this is the Python book dict


//set up DB connection
db = mysql.connector.connect()
cursor = db.cursor()


sql = "INSERT INTO BOOKS (title, summary, number) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)"
val = ("Title1", "Summary", "Number3") 

cursor.execute(sql, val)
db.commit()
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use the executemany statement

```
books =  [{'title': 'Game of Thrones', 'summary': 'summary detail',  'number': 4},
```

{'title': 'James and the Giant Peach', 'summary': 'summary detail', 'number': 1}]

```
#first store the books values into a list of tuples
new_books=[]
for item in books:
   my_tuple=(item['title'],item['summary'],item['number'])
   new_books.append(my_tuple)
cursor = connection.cursor()
sql = "INSERT INTO BOOKS (title, summary, number) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)"
cursor.executemany(sql, new_books)
connection.commit()
```

Comment: @Tibebes.M I should edited the answer with more details

Comment: If I have additional fields on each of the books such as reserved as in {'title': 'Game of Thrones', 'summary': 'summary detail', 'number': 4, reserved: 'False'} what is the best way to filter those out fields that I don't to save as book.values() will have fields that I don't want to save down, assuming some sort of one to one mapping with an object?

Comment: @devC i didnt really understand what you want to do to the additional field,are you trying to save them as well or you dont want to save them

Comment: @helodevZcoder I don't want to save the additional field(s)

Answer (score 1):

Just loop through the list and prepare the second arg. for `cursor.execute` by either using [`dict.values()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.values) or indexing the keys one by one and creating a tuple there.

try something like this:

```py
books = [
    {'title': 'Game of Thrones', 'summary': 'summary detail', 'number': 4},
    {'title': 'James and the Giant Peach', 'summary': 'summary detail', 'number': 1}
]

...

sql = "INSERT INTO BOOKS (title, summary, number) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)"

for book in books:
    cursor.execute(sql, book.values())
    # or
    # cursor.execute(sql, (book['title'], book['summary], book['number']))
```

Comment: If I have additional fields on each of the books such as reserved as in `{'title': 'Game of Thrones', 'summary': 'summary detail', 'number': 4, reserved: 'False'}` what is the best way to filter those out fields that I don't to save as `book.values()` will have fields that I don't want to save down, assuming some sort of one to one mapping with an object?

Comment: use the second approach in that case (manual indexing)

Answer (score 1):

You could create a list from the values of the dictionaries and use it in `executemany`:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO BOOKS (title, summary, number) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)"
values = [tuple(d.values()) for d in books]

cursor.executemany(sql, values)
```

The `values` list looks like this:

```
[('Game of Thrones', 'summary detail', 4), ('James and the Giant Peach', 'summary detail', 1)]
```